# Hidden view above RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to make some hidden filters options above recyclerview (for example like in old versions of spotify):

[image]

How to do that? I use AppBar above my recycler.

Comment: So what is the intended behavior of this views? Should they show when you scroll or when you click something?

Comment: When I try to scroll above 1st element.

Comment: Make that layout visible when the user swipes down the recyclerview in addonscrollListener @MateuszKaflowski

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as mentioned in answer above (with changing visibility of searching view so when it is visibility is View.GONE the recycleView will move up, using ContraintLayout). Or to add aditional ViewHolder to yours adapter (like TopSearchViewHolder which contains yours searching view). 
Like this (in getItemViewType you would decide when to display particular viewType) :

```
      override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val orderViewHolder = OrderViewHolder.create(parent).apply {
            listener = this@OrdersAdapter.listener
        }
        return when (viewType) {
            R.layout.list_item1 -> orderViewHolder
            R.layout.list_item2 -> NetworkStateViewHolder.create(parent, retryCallback)
            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown view type $viewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            R.layout.list_item1 -> (holder as OrderViewHolder).bind(getItem(position))
            R.layout.list_item2 -> (holder as NetworkStateViewHolder).bind(getItem(position))
        }
    }
   override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (hasExtraRow() && position == itemCount - 1) {
            R.layout.list_item1
        } else {
            R.layout.list_item2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to do what you want

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        if (dy > 0) {
                         //You should HIDE filter view here
                        } else if (dy < 0) {
                            System.out.println("Scrolled Upwards");
                            if (mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                                //this is the top of the RecyclerView
                               System.out.println("==================================== >>>> Detect top of the item List");
                             //You should visible filter view here
                            } else {
                              //You should HIDE filter view here
                             }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No Vertical Scrolled");
                            //You should HIDE filter view here
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I am testing this solution now. How to add "filter view" with scrolling effect?

Comment: I updated my answer with comment(ex: //You should visible filter view here) please check this now

Answer (score 2):

Use the RecyclerView scroll listener as I mentioned in the comment like this

```
private static int firstVisibleInListview;

firstVisibleInListview = yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

@Override
 public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,int newState){
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView,newState);

    }

 @Override
  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,int dx,int dy){
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView,dx,dy);

    int currentFirstVisible = 
                yourLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); 



    if(currentFirstVisible > firstVisibleInListview){
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{      
    filterView.setVisibvility(View.GONE);
        }
       }
      }
    });
```

**XML for RecyclerView layout**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

//use FilterView here
//hide this view initially.
   <Filter-view
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/filterView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/moviesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_200dp"
    android:id="@+id/noMoviesMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/noirden_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_18sp"
    android:text="@string/the_are_no_movies_showing_right_now_please_check_later"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

let me know after you try this

Comment: you wanted the filter view to be hidden when recyclerview is in the top? @MateuszKaflowski

Comment: When I start activity and try to scroll up the listener wont be called.

Comment: so you want the filter view to be shown when recyclerview is on top? @MateuszKaflowski

Comment: @ Brahma Datta Yes.

Comment: And when it should be hidden? I'm sorry in the screenshot i understood filter view should be shown only when user scrolls down @MateuszKaflowski .Can you explain it in short?

Comment: It should behave like first element o recycler view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193690/discussion-between-brahma-datta-and-mateusz-kaflowski).

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int dy = 0;
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            final boolean isOnTop = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0;
            if (isOnTop && newState == 1)
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (dy <= 0) {
                            KLog.d("show filter");
                        }
                    }
                }, 20);
            else if (newState == 1 && dy > 0)
                KLog.e("gone filter");

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            this.dy = dy;
        }
    });
```

Not super elegant and still need to find a way to animate hidden view.